# Posterior pdf is proper if and only if the conditionals are

Tags: probability, self-study

**Note: This is a homework problem so PLEASE DO NOT PROVIDE A COMPLETE SOLUTION. Some gentle hints would be good.**

Let pdf $f(x\mid\theta,\, \phi) = g(\theta;\, x)$ be given and unidentifiable in $\phi$. Consider a prior $\pi(\theta, \phi)$. Show that the posterior is proper if and only if both the conditionals $\pi(\phi\mid\theta)$ and $\pi(\theta\mid x)$ are proper.

**My Attempt**

\begin{align}
f(\theta,\, \phi,\, x) &= f(x\mid \theta,\, \phi) \pi(\theta,\, \phi)\\
&= g(\theta; x) \pi(\phi\mid \theta) \pi(\theta)\\
&= \pi(\theta\mid x)\pi(\phi\mid \theta) m(x)\pi(\theta).
\end{align}

Also, \begin{align}
f(\theta,\, \phi\mid x) &= \frac{f(\theta,\, \phi,\, x)}{h(x)}\\
&= \frac{\pi(\theta\mid x)\pi(\phi\mid \theta) m(x)\pi(\theta)}{h(x)},
\end{align}
where $h(x) = \iint f(\theta,\, \phi,\, x) \, \mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi$.

But surely, that the l.h.s. integrates to a finite number also depends on how $\pi(\theta)$ behaves, right? Can we infer anything on it from the two conditionals being proper?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "unidentifiable in " is not a standard term. Do you mean that the conditional density of $x$ does not depend on ?

Comment: @Xi'an unfortunately, that is how it's written in the homework problem and I'm also confused. But since the instructor also wrote $f(x \mid \theta,\, \phi) = g(\theta; \, x)$, I think he meant that it does not depend on $\phi$.